# Use array from model in form drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

In my model I have:

```
 @category_check = ['cables', 'printers', 'monitors', 'accessories', 'towers', 'interaction']
```

It is used for a validates, now I want to display the array as options in my form. This does not work:

```
<%= f.label :category %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :category, @category_check, {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>
```

Do I have to make another instance variable in my controller or is there a way to display each in a drop down from the model variable? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to call something like this

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, @category_check, :to_s, :to_s, {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>
```

This will pass :to_s to each element of the the @category_check collection.

Comment: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access that array through the model, assuming you have one instantiated:

```
@my_model.category_check
```

However it looks like those categories are static, so ideally they'd be a class-level constant:

```
class MyModel

  CATEGORY_CHECK = ['cables', 'printers', 'monitors', 'accessories', 'towers', 'interaction']
end
```

Then you could access it anywhere, without an instance of the class around:

```
MyModel::CATEGORY_CHECK
```

As Lalitharyani mentions in his answer, you'll also need to provide name and value methods to call on each item of the array so that the form helper knows what to display.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing one parameter on the method call:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, @category_check, {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>
```

should be:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, :category_id, @category_check, {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>
```